# SSD Latency over USB

Tags: usb, ssd, usb-3, usb-c, latency

I've just learned that (internal) SSD latency is in the ballpark of some microseconds (1/1000th a millisecond) and HDD latency is in the range of milliseconds.

I went out and bought a USB-C 3.2 Gen 2 SSD to take advantage of the drop in latency. But I can't find an answer online regarding how connecting over USB might make an impact.

I've read posts claiming SSD latency over USB is a few milliseconds, and some others which claim it's still in the microseconds. Given that using external SSDs as boot drives is reasonably common, I hoped there would be some reliable discussion on the topic, but I haven't been able to find any.

**Is anyone aware of a possible approximation/guess about external SSDs' latency?**
Is it still in the microseconds, or is it longer?

Please cite your sources if it's not much trouble, or not.

Comment: Since you have already bought the SSD, why not just testing by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

This is a HD Tune benchmark, *well within microseconds range*, for an external SanDisk Extreme Portable SSD V2, USB 3.2 Gen 2.

[image]

Comment: I'm reading 0.181ms (which is much better than a typical HDD)

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Thought picture says more than a thousand words.